# Magento 2 :upload file type restrict to pdf only

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, file-upload

I have created a custom file type customer attribute

```
$customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
    'price_agreement',
    [
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Price Agreement File',
        'input' => 'file',
        'source' => '',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'position' => 200,
        'system' => false,
        'backend' => ''
    ]
    );

$customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'price_agreement')->setData('is_user_defined',1)
                                 ->setData('is_required',0)
                                 ->setData('default_value','')
                                 ->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']) 
                                 ->save();                                 

}
```

I want to restrict this field to upload only .pdf format. No other format should not be able to upload.Where can I set setAllowedExtensions for this attribute.

Any help??

Comment: Try to check the below process of adding a product attribute of file type. It may help you..
https://webkul.com/blog/create-and-manage-product-file-type-attribute-in-magento-2/

Comment: Did you find any solution for this if so can you please post here.

Answer (score 2):

Please try with below code:
step1 :

```
<input type="file" name="custom_file_name" id="custom_file_name" title="PDF File" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
```

step2 :

```
<?php
namespace Adamsmage\Fileupload\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;

class Fileupload extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     */
    protected $filesystem;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploader
     */
    protected $fileUploader;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        ...
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        UploaderFactory $fileUploader
    )
    {
        $this->messageManager       = $messageManager;
        ...
        $this->filesystem           = $filesystem;
        $this->fileUploader         = $fileUploader;

        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $uploadedFile = $this->uploadpdfFile();
    }

    public function uploadpdfFile()
    {
        // this folder will be created inside "pub/media" folder
        $yourFolderName = 'custom-folder-name/';

        // "my_custom_file" is the HTML input file name
        $yourInputFileName = 'custom_file_name';

        try{
            $file = $this->getRequest()->getFiles($yourInputFileName);
            $fileName = ($file && array_key_exists('name', $file)) ? $file['name'] : null;

            if ($file && $fileName) {
                $target = $this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($yourFolderName);        

                /** @var $uploader \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader */
                $uploader = $this->fileUploader->create(['fileId' => $yourInputFileName]);

                // set allowed file extensions
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['pdf']);

                // allow folder creation
                $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);

                // rename file name if already exists 
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);

                // upload file in the specified folder
                $result = $uploader->save($target);

                if ($result['file']) {
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('File has been successfully uploaded.')); 
                }

                return $target . $uploader->getUploadedFileName();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: if other file format uploaded, need to show error message, that this type is not allowed. how can we do that @Mansuri.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `accept` attribute ex: `accept=".csv, text/csv"` in the input tag. Then only pdf's can be chosen.

`<input id="custom_file_name" type="file"  data-reset="true" class="action-upload" name="<?= $block->escapeHtml($fieldNameFile) ?>">`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file